# Laravel custom validation error messages

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I have a custom "base" validator

```
class BaseUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    ...

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'password.min' => 'Custom error',
        ];
    }
}
```

And other validator extends "base" class

```
class RegisterUserRequest extends BaseUserRequest
{
    ...

    public function messages()
    {
        return parent::messages();
    }
}
```

When I try to trigger `password:min` error on form, which uses `RegisterUserRequest`, I get default message instead "Custom error" message. What's wrong with my `RegisterUserRequest` class?
If I use `BaseUserRequest`, I get my "Custom error" message. Something is wrong with class inheritance.

**UPDATE (QUESTION SOLVED)**: I forgot to register rules on validation
not

```
return Validator::make($data, (new RegisterUserRequest())->rules());
```

but

```
return Validator::make($data, (new RegisterUserRequest())->rules(), (new RegisterUserRequest())->messages());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
   php artisan make:request BaseUserRequest
```

> // app/Http/Requests/BaseUserRequest.php

```
public function messages()
{
        return [
        'password.min' => 'Custom error',
       ];  
}
```

> // app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php

```
use App\Http\Requests\BaseUserRequest;

public function register(BaseUserRequest $request)
{
   // register code here
}
```